# How to choose which RAM for my PC

Tags: memory

I am trying to add some RAM to my system.

There are my specifications:
CPU: AMD Phenom II X4 965

Graphics: Nvidia GeForce GTX 760

Hard drive: Samsung EVO Pro 256 GB SSD

Mainboard: Asus M4N72-E

Memory: 3 x 2 GB

[Memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkMSH.png)

The Picture was taken from a tool called CPU-Z. I have also searched for the manufacturer Website of the mainboard and got this information:

4 x DIMM, 16 GB, DDR2 1066*/1300(O.C.)/800/667 ECC

Non-ECC,Un-buffered Memory

Dual Channel memory architecture

*Due to AMD CPU limitation, DDR2 1066MHz is supported by AM3/AM2+ CPU for one DIMM per channel only. Refer to www.asus.com for the memory QVL (Qualified Vendors Lists).
**Due to OS limitation, when installing total memory of 4GB capacity or more, Windows® 32-bit operation system may only recognize less than 3GB. Hence, a total installed memory of less than 3GB is recommended.

A few days ago i was in a shop and the salesman said that i can use any DDR2 Ram. So i ordered a 4 GB Ram stick from amazon and today i send it back because with the new Ram Stick i got Bluescreens with the memory_managment error.

So any advise or help would be great, and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently using 3 sticks of 2 GB DDR2-800 RAM.
This is an strange combination because 2 of those sticks run in dual-channel mode, but the 3rd runs in single-channel.
Ideally you would use either 1 pair of identically spec RAM-sticks. Or 2 pairs of identically spec sticks.
(The 2 yellow slots form a pair and the 2 black slots form the other pair. Or a pair consist of 1 black and 1 yellow. You'll need to check the manual for that. That can vary quite a lot from motherboard to motherboard.)

The paired (dual-channel) combinations can ONLY be used if the sticks are DDR2-800 or DDR2-677. With the slightly faster DDR2-1066 (or 1300) the CPU can't handle it. (In that case only a single stick can be used in each of the pairs.)
Both sticks in a pair should have the same specs: Same speed and same size. It is best if they are even the same brand/model stick.

You added a 4th stick, with a different specification then the already present 2 GB stick on the other side of the pair. As you discovered that is unstable.

Either get a single extra 2GB DDR2-800 stick. (If you can find one with same specs as the existing 2GB sticks.)
Or get a pair of DDR2-800 4GB sticks (and remove 1 of the existing 2 GB sticks) so you get 1 pair of 2x2 and 1 pair of 2x4 for 12 GB in total.

As Frank Thomas rightly mentioned: Check the Asus compatibility lists for the exact specifications, but in general you should be able to use generic DDR2-800 RAM as long they are in matched pairs.

Comment: hi thx for the tipp. Now it works just remove the 1 2 gb module. Now i got in one pair the single 4gb stick and in the other 2x2gb modules and no more bluescreens. Thanks again

Comment: Glad to be able to help. The only drawback to this config is  a minor speed penalty (2-3%) compared to a full dual-channel setup. You won't notice that as you already started in such a configuration and the benefit from more RAM is much bigger anyway.

Comment: well i get the second 4 gb ram module on friday. The same on so on Friday everything should be ok thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the specs for your [motherboard model](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4N72E/), and consult its instructions on populating RAM channels, to determine how many chips you need and how you will distribute them.
2. Consult the Manufacturers [Hardware Compatibility List (HCL) for RAM modules](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socketAM3/M4N72-E/M4N72-E_Memory_QVL.zip) [.zip file, why does asus do that....] for that motherboard.
3. Select a make/model of RAM module from the HCL that matches your specifications for Type, Size, Voltage, Frequency, and number of chips, and are also commercially available in your region and your price range.

Comment: More likely than not he got the wrong clock speed.  Set your motherboard to 800MHz and use 4x4GB DDR2 800.  That should work, regardless of brand.

Comment: clock speed is on auto in the Bios. 677 or so i belive and btw is it a bad idea to mix 2 gb modules with 4 gb modules?

Comment: thanks for the Specifications. I ordere another 4 GB Module acording to it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll tell you the easiest way.
Crucial has a scanner which can tell you all the RAM cards compatible.
It is not 100% accurate, just be sure you are buying a card with same clock and CL(CL=6 in your case) as the RAM you have already.

[Scanner](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/systemscanner)

Hope i helped!